# Spring exception handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

So from what I understood and tried, I could create `@ExceptionHandler` at controller level to handle a specific exception. I also can move things to `@ControllerAdvice` to catch exceptions globally.

I'm unsure about one thing however, let's say I have a `@Controller` that have 3 different methods, all these methods could throw a `DataIntegrityViolationException`, I want to return a specific error-message for each method. What is considered best practice to handle this?

I'm trying to avoid catching exceptions inside each method in order not to clutter the code.

Comment: i don't see a huge difference between \@Advice and \@Handler. however, if the logic to get the right error message is specific to this class, i'd keep it in this class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from when did catching exceptions specific to one piece of code becomes 'clutter'. (unless you are repeating the same catch block over and over again, but you are not doing that - you need specific message per method). As you have listed, you have 3 options:

1. Catch exception in each particular method. It will be more specific, adheres to SRP at the method level, gives you complete control over how you handle the exception.
2. Write an exception handler for that controller. But this means, you will have to have some sort of branching (if-else) to determine which error message to send on which exception. This means maintaining this method in the long run might be painful. Someone looking at your code will not know that an exception might be thrown and is handled at a different place.
3. Write a controller advice - Unless you are catching really global exceptions which none of the individual controllers can/should handle (like missing parameters, some generic 500 or 400 case which you don't want your controller to worry about, since they're not core to your business), there really isn't much value to have an @Advice which is an exception handler. Personally, I think, to some extent it is fragmented logic in multiple places.

Think of yourself as someone who will maintain your code after 3-5 years. Will it make her/his life easier to extend/modify in general maintain this approach (unless you document it and maintain that document)?

Comment: I thought generally its better to avoid try-catch blocks inside a spring controller but according to what you said I'm wrong. My question now is, what return type should be used if I'm going to return either a `User` (for example) or an `Error`? Should I use `ResponseEntity`? Thanks

Comment: Most of it comes down to best practices and as such I don't believe there is right or wrong. As to what your return type should be, it depends on the the API contract (if an endpoint) or the flow logic (if you should render a UI).  Again, think about why would you want to "return" normally when there is an error.

Comment: I'm creating REST apis that responses in json, my method might return an actual bean populated from the database or it might return an error if an error occurs. Thus two different data types, I went with ResponseEntity and I fill it with either the bean or the error. Are there any other ways to handle this that I'm not aware about?